# Some certain neon instruction in <arm_neon.h> is not available in Jetson Xavier (ARMv8.2)

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, arm, neon, armv8

"vld1q_u16_x2" existing in <arm_neon.h> is not available in Jetson Xavier (ARMv8.2). An example code is the same as the attached code. I've tried the code on M1, A53, and A72 and it all works fine.

However, Jetson Xavier gives the following warnings and errors:
"*warning: implicit declaration of function 'vld1q_u16_x2*'" and "*error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'uint16x8x2_t {aka struct uint16x8x2_t}' from type 'int'. src1 = vldlq_u16_x2(&origin)*" .

Does ARMv8.2 not support this instruction? we would like to know a solution for this.

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

int main()
{
    uint16x8x2_t src1, src2;
    uint16_t origin = 0x33;

    src1 = vld1q_u16_x2(&origin);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As per Jake's answer below, the problem is a lack of gcc support for Aarch32. You can file a bug about that at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ but looks like for your platform you can also just target Aarch64

Answer (score 1):

It's not really about ARMv8.2, it's GCC.  [GCC's 32-bit arm_neon.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/arm/arm_neon.h) is currently [missing](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71233) quite a few functions which are supposed to be there.

These are [a fairly recent addition to clang](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/568421baa5a4cdb7bb7c5ac323c939492ee3f052) as well; they weren't available there before version 9.

AArch64 support on GCC tends to be better; a lot of these functions are present in [GCC's 64-bit arm_neon.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/aarch64/arm_neon.h), though they should really be present in both.  Last time I looked there were a handful of functions present in 32-bit mode but missing from the 64-bit headers, a handful of functions missing from both 32-bit and 64-bit, but a few dozen function present in 64-bit but missing in 32-bit.

FWIW, the situation on the clang side is better; they are only missing a few functions... if you can use clang instead, that may be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

All those `x2/x3/x4` suffices aren't supported in `aarch32` mode regardless of the toolchain even though it would be very well possible since ARM32 neon has appropriate instructions.

You should limit the target to `aarch64`.

It is stupid, and NEON intrinsics badly needs a revamp: there's no `vtbl1q`, `vtbl2q`, `vtbl3q`, and `vtbl4q` even though ARM64 has `tbl/tbx` instructions that accept 128bit vectors.

MS Visual Studio already comes with its own(?) `arm64_neon.h` that supports all those above.

PS: 걍 어셈블리로 짜세요.

Comment: Are you looking for the [vqtbl1q/vqtbx3q instructions](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#q=vqtb)?

Comment: @BenClark What?????? Thank you. But what is the `q` for????

Comment: the q is for "quad-word" ie 128-byte. Normally it's just after the instruction as the output is 128-byte, but sometimes there's a q at the start if there's an intermediate step that needs 128-byte (especially for saturating commands to cope with overflow etc)

Comment: I was talking about the first `q` which is usually the saturation flag. And I don't know what it's there for since the instructions `tbl` and `tbx` don't come with any flag.